# Cypress custom command is not recognized, randomly failing

Tags: cypress

Our custom commands sometimes are failing in one test and passing in second test, and sometimes works well.

```
context('Test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.platformLogin('someuser@test.com');
  });
});
```

We are importing commands correctly in `support/index.js` file.

`import './commands';`

And again, sometimes its working fine, not sure what is wrong.

Error message we are getting:

> TypeError: cy.platformLogin is not a function

Comment: can you show the command definition?

Comment: @dwelle  `Cypress.Commands.add('commandName', (email, password) => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'someurlhere',
    body: { bodyhere },
  }).then(response => {
    expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
  });
});`

Comment: If that's really it, then you're naming it `commandName` instead of `platformLogin`

Comment: @dwelle I just gave example of commandName.  @dwelle `Cypress.Commands.add('platformLogin', (email, password) => { cy.request({ method: 'POST', url: 'someurlhere', body: { bodyhere }, }).then(response => { expect(response.status).to.eq(200); }); });`

Comment: sorry about that, you never know these days :sweat_smile:. Otherwise, I have no clue :/. Either way, I'd add the above into your post, for others (and we can delete these comments). You can also possibly post a minimal working reproducible repo.